# upsert into oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `table` with columns `id, name, position, capture_date, modified_date, comments`.
I am trying to do a simple `upsert` which is driving me crazy. 
When the table is empty, it has to insert, but when its not empty it has to update the comments column row which has the same position, if its different it has to insert a new row instead of updating the existing one.
When the table is empty, i used this merge statement to create the first row.

This works fine.
But, second row has to be

`1, john, 2, 01-JUL-15, 23-JUL-15, 'world'`

In this case, the data is almost same except that the position value is 2, so a new row has to be inserted instead of updating the existing row's position to 2.
That is what my merge statement is doing. Any ideas to work on this please.

```
    merge into customers a
using(select 1 as customer_id, 'john' as customer_name, '1' as position, '01-JUL-15' as capture_date, 
      sysdate as  modified_date, 'hello' as comments from dual) b
  on(a.customer_id=b.customer_id)
when matched then
update set a.customer_id = b.customer_id, a.customer_name = b.customer_name, 
a.position = b.position, a.capture_date= b.capture_date, a.modified_date = b.modified_date,
a.comments=b.comments
when not matched then
insert(a.customer_id, a.customer_name, a.position, a.capture_date, a.modified_date, a.comments)
values(b.customer_id, b.customer_name, b.position, b.capture_date, b.modified_date, b.comments)
```

I have created the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7baf78/6)

Comment: The statement you posted doesn't appear to be correct.  The query in the `using` clause isn't selecting from a table-- I assume you are missing a `from dual`.  And the `on` clause is missing.  That's what tells you whether to do an insert or an update.  I'm guessing that this clause is incorrect in your actual statement but since it's not included, it's hard to know.  I would assume that your `when matched` should not be updating the `id` column.

Comment: @JustinCave I updated the code, i missed out when i copied the code

Comment: Can you please post a syntactically correct statement. Table is not a valid table name, john should be 'john', vales must be values. Please take a look at the Oracle documentation on merge:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: @Rene I have made a sample statement, i know its not correct. I read the documentation and i couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Rene I have created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7baf78/6

Comment: What is unclear about the error message you get?

ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."CUSTOMER_ID"

Comment: @Rene I'm seeing that too, i don't understand where I'm missing

Answer (score 5):

So lessons learned:

- 1 post the original query not some faulty surrogate.
- 2 post any error message you get.

The error message you get is:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."CUSTOMER_ID"
```

Solution: remove a.customer_id from the update clause.

```
merge into customers a
using (select 1 as customer_id
             ,'john' as customer_name
             ,'1' as position
             ,'01-JUL-15' as capture_date
             ,sysdate as modified_date
             ,'hello' as comments
         from dual) b
on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id)
when matched then
   update
      set a.customer_name = b.customer_name
         ,a.position      = b.position
         ,a.capture_date  = b.capture_date
         ,a.modified_date = b.modified_date
         ,a.comments      = b.comments
when not matched then
   insert
      (a.customer_id
      ,a.customer_name
      ,a.position
      ,a.capture_date
      ,a.modified_date
      ,a.comments)
   values
      (b.customer_id
      ,b.customer_name
      ,b.position
      ,b.capture_date
      ,b.modified_date
      ,b.comments)
```

Comment: I am getting invalid sql statement

Comment: It runs fine on my Oracle database. Don't know why SQLFiddle reports that error.

Comment: I'm unable to insert a new row, if the position is updated to 2, The row with position as 1 is updated. How to solve the problem. i've been banging my head since 4 hours

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I tried redoing in sqlfiddle, but its not working for some reason. that's the exact table i have created in my local. First time, the record is inserted fine, but the 2nd record is not inserted instead its getting updated. I need this because, first time the table is empty, i need the record to be inserted.

Comment: Look at your `on` clause. That is used to match. The existing row and the new row you want to insert both have 1 as the `customer_id`, which means they match, so it will do an update. If you want a new row, you need to give it a `customer_id` that doesn't already exist in the table.

Comment: @daivrz Oh, i didn't understand that was the reason behind it. So I tried to do an `insert where not exists` and `update when exists`. That made it work for me